# Form Post results in bad request 400

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am experimenting with user authentication (and MEAN in general) and I am stuck on a curious 400 bad request error.

I have a simple login form that posts to a API endpoint, and the server always displays a 400 bad request.   I have checked the dev console in crhome, and I can't seem to find the post data.  Further, what seperates my issue from many of the other ones on Stack Overflow is I am not using Ajax, nor do I see an error message from Angular or in the Node Console... only the status code in the node and Chrome dev console.

My code is below, thank you in advance!

**Here is my form code:**

```
<form class="form-inline navbar-form navbar-right" action="/todo" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" ng-model="loginData.rememberme"> Remember me
            </label>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>

        </form>
```

**And now my middleware code.**

```
    var express = require('express');
var app = express(); // create our app w/ express
var router = express.Router();
var session = require('cookie-session');
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); // mongoose for mongodb
var morgan = require('morgan'); // log requests to the console (express4)
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // pull information from HTML POST (express4)
var methodOverride = require('method-override'); // simulate DELETE and PUT (express4)
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var path = require('path');
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var passport = require('passport'),
  LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;


// configuration =================

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/todoApp'); // connect to mongoDB

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/')); // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  'extended': 'true'
})); // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parse application/json
//app.use(bodyParser.json({
  //type: 'application/vnd.api+json'
//})); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(session({
  secret: 'Noble64'
}));
//app.use(express.session({ secret: 'noble64' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form

        // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
        // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
        User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
            // if there are any errors, return the error before anything else
            if (err)
                return done(err);

            // if no user is found, return the message
            if (!user)
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash

            // if the user is found but the password is wrong
            if (!user.validPassword(password))
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata

            // all is well, return successful user
            return done(null, user);
        });

    }));

    app.post('/todo',
      passport.authenticate('local-login'),
      function(req, email, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form

          // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
          // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
          User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
              // if there are any errors, return the error before anything else
              if (err)
                  return done(err);

              // if no user is found, return the message
              if (!user)
                  return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash

              // if the user is found but the password is wrong
              if (!user.validPassword(password))
                  return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata

              // all is well, return successful user
              return done(null, user);
          });
          res.json(req.user);

      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are connecting to the database properly? You aren't providing a port while connecting to the database. Example:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/todoApp');
```

Comment: It was connecting to the db just fine before I added the login form, but I can give it a try.